# How to update and insert records after every 1 minute in sqlite?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-views

I have created a django project which contains one table. I want to automatically update the records in sqlite databse after every minute. How can be this done?

I have already used time.sleep(18000) library of python but it didn't worked.

In if:else statement insert and update operations are performed.

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    while True: 
        r1 = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:2000/_nodes")
        script = r1.json()
        write = script['nodes']['data']
        ts1 = script['nodes']['time']
        print("write   ",write)
        print("ts1  ",ts1)

        r2 = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:2000/_nodes")
        script = r2.json()
        read = script['nodes']['total']
        ts2 = script['nodes']['time']
        print("read   ",read)
        print("ts2  ",ts2)

        new_count = write+read
        new_t = (ts1+ts2)/2
        print ("new count", new_count)
        print("new ts", new_t)

        q = data.objects.filter()

        if q.exists():
            test1 = data.fetch()
            for row in test1:
                test1={
                    'id':row.id,
                    'sum': row.sum,
                    'ts': row.ts,
                    'status': row.status
                    }
            prev_t = test1['ts']
            prev_count = test1['sum']

            if(test1['id']==1):
                if(new_count < prev_count):
                    test2 = data.objects.get(id=1)
                    print("TEST2 Type", type(test2))
                    print(test2)
                    test2 = data(id=1,sum=new_count,ts=new_t,status="restarted")
                    test2.save()
                    print(test2)
                    print(type(test2))
                else:
                    test1 = data.fetch()
                    test2 = data.objects.get(id=1)
                    print("TEST2 Type", type(test2))
                    print(test2)
                    test2 = data(id=1,sum=new_count,ts=new_t,status="updated")
                    test2.save()
                    print(test2)
                    print(type(test2))
   
        else:
            test2 = data(id=1,sum=new_count,ts=new_t,status="firstQuery")
            test2.save()
            print (test2)
            print("Fresh record created")
            test2 = data.fetch()
            for row2 in test2:
                test2={
                    'id':row2.id,
                    'sum': row2.sum,
                    'ts': row2.ts,
                    'status': row2.status
                }
                print(test2)
                print(type(test2))
```

Comment: It did not update data automatically after every minute, instead it only updates data when web page is refreshed. I want to update the database irrespective of refreshing webpage.

Comment: you should use any of available asynchronous task queues like celery or django- background-tasks

Comment: use celery with django-celery-beat. It allows you to schedule your tasks and execute your task every 1 minute as well.